# How to measure the 'time units' required for the execution of assembly code

Tags: algorithm, assembly, quicksort

I am going through this book called " An Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms" ( by Robert Sedgewick and Philippe Flajolet ), and in the first chapter, when they are trying to analyse the quick sort algorithm, they say something which I just haven't been able to understand at all.
In trying to compute the 'resource requirements' of a loop namely something like:

```
while( a[++i] < v );
```

they said that it could be written in assembly as:

```
LOOP INC I,1
     CMP V,A(I)
     BL LOOP
```

so far so good I guess, but then they mentioned ( that for a first estimation ) it is reasonable to think of one iteration of the loop consuming 'four time units', "one for each memory reference" they say.
I have no idea what is it that they mean by 'units of time', and from where did the quantitative measure of 'four' come up from and what assembly code has to with it all, the quoted phrase for what I take was to be the explanation of the argument is also something I am at a loss to understand.
Just to clarify, I do not really want someone to explain Quicksort to me, I want to know what these abstractions in the analysis that were made mean independently.
Could someone please help me out here?

Comment: I believe the time unit is a clock cycle. I dont get this 4 either since as I see that 3 instructions (INC, CMP and BL. LOOP seems to be a label) Maybe they assume that one of this instruction is take 2 clock cycle to execute

Comment: @eraklon `CMP V,A(I)` has a memory operand, so it should take an extra cycle to perform a fetch.

Comment: @fuz Yes thats my bet too.

Comment: @fuz: I think `cmp V, A(I)` has 3 memory operands: V, A(), and I.  Otherwise I don't see how we get 4 total if V or I are registers.  That's totally ridiculous of course; maybe VAX could do indexed addressing with a memory index, but this seems too high-level to model real machines very well.  Or else each instruction fetch is one memory access, and `A(I)` is a memory operand.

Comment: @PeterCordes Each instruction fetch is a memory access, too.

Comment: @PeterCordes (and others). no one has yet mentioned that the book is assuming that I and V are being kept in registers, otherwise, the increment would count as 3 "units" (fetch, read (I), write (i), assuming zero time for the increment).